# Getting a character as input

Tags: java, character, primitive-types

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ParseStatement {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        char x=input.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

What does "charAt(0)" mean in Java?

Why do we use it?

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions at once.

Comment: You must search before asking here. Look at this = http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_charat.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input.next()` will read a `String` before a space or a newline and `charAt(0)` will be the first character of that read String.

For example

```
String str = "hai";
System.out.println(str.charAt(0));
System.out.println(str.charAt(1));
System.out.println(str.charAt(2));
```

Output of the above code will be

```
h
a
i
```

#### Use of `CharAt(index)`

`CharAt(index)` is a method in the `String` class which can be used to get the character at a specified index from a `String`.

java doc for [`charAt(index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29)